# Usage of "electrics" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

First of all I'm not used to hearing the term "electrics." I'm willing to accept it as valid, but what should the usage be? Is it a synonym of "electronics", or "electricity", or something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a brief [discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/conversation/electrics-tag) I have edited away the "electrics" tag in favour of [electrical-system](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-system)

Answer (score 6):

Right now I don't see anything with [electrics](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrics) that I think merits the existence of the tag.  Everything in there should really be tagged with something more useful (like [avionics](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avionics), [instruments](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruments), [electrical-system](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-system) (none of those yet?), [electric-aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-aircraft), or [personal-electronic-devices](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-electronic-devices)), and most of what's there already has a more appropriate tag.

I'm not universally opposed to having an "electrics" tag, but it doesn't seem to add much over the more specific tags and I can't think of a situation where it would be used *without* needing a more specific tag.

Answer (score 3):

There are two separate things, I think:

1. electrical systems -- everything from the generators to the batteries, circuit breakers, lights, etc
2. electronics or avionics -- anything based on transistor technology, GPS, engine monitor, etc. I would even include a cavity tube-based transponder

Comment: I agree with that, are you saying electrics can mean both?

Comment: i think its a British term that means #1

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5699/electronic-vs-electric

Comment: It's definitely British/Commonwealth usage.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Electrics = wiring, circuit breakers etc.

Answer (score 0):

There has been more than a little talk in the media lately about the possibility or inevitability of electric powered aircraft in the future.  Perhaps this tag is more appropriately referring to electric powered aircraft.  The tag name could be edited to make this clear but I would love to see some more discussion about the possibility of clean, quiet power plants.

Comment: voretaq7 suggested "electric-aircraft" in his answer, and I think that would be a much more clear name for tagging this subject. It seems like "electrics" already has a closer definition of "electronics" and it may be confusing to use it differently.

Comment: Yes I see that now.  I got bogged down trying to read a long sentence with multiple nested parenthesis.  Thx